# Laravel: Parse arbitrary URL to its corresponding Controller/Route?

Tags: php, laravel, routes

Given I have an arbitrary URL mapped (amongst many others) like this

```
...
Route::get('/foobar/{parameter}', 'MyFoobarController@index');
...
```

How can I "reverse parse/resolve" the URL (`like http://localhost/foobar/foo`) into this configured controller (`MyFoobarController`) again? Please note: I am not talking about the current Request but a general approach to parse any URL that is mapped in Laravel to its corresponding Controller and Action (anywhere in the code independent of the current request). Thanks!

**Update:** It should also correctly match Routes, that have parameters in them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compare the URL path, to the paths added to the router. So let's take your example:

```php
Route::get('/foobar', 'MyFoobarController@index');
```

You can use the `Route` facade to get a list of all registered routes:

```php
// This is your URL as a string
$url = 'http://localhost/foobar';

// Extract the path from that URL
$path = trim(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH), '/');

// Iterate over the routes until you find a match
foreach (Route::getRoutes() as $route) {
    if ($route->getPath() == $path) {
        // Access the action with $route->getAction()
        break;
    }
}
```

The `getAction` method will return an array containing the relevant information about the action mapped for that route. You can check out the [`Illuminate\Routing\Route`](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Routing/Route.html) API for more info on what methods are available for you to use once you have matched a route.

Comment: Hmmm... I don't see anything here about handling parameters? If the $url that I want to resolve is '/page/foo'  and the route it should match is 'page/:slug' then what will $route->getPath() return? Certainly not something that will compare equal to 'page/foo'?

Comment: this is not ok when the path  have various parameters

Answer (score 0):

```
   private function getMatchRoutes($request)
    {
        $referer = $request->header('Referer');
        $refererPath  = parse_url($referer,PHP_URL_PATH);
        $routes = Route::getRoutes()->getRoutes();
        $matchedRoute = null;
        foreach ($routes as $route) {
            $route->compiled = (new RouteCompiler($route))->compile();
            if (is_null($route->getCompiled())) continue;
            if (preg_match($route->getCompiled()->getRegex(), rawurldecode($refererPath))) {
                $matchedRoute =  $route;
            }
        }
        if (is_null($matchedRoute)) return $matchedRoute;
        return explode('@',$matchedRoute->getActionName())[0];
    }
```

the codes above i wrote is to get controller/action from request referer ,you can replace it by a valid url, try it , may be helpful ~~~